# Why do some planes in blender bend on a different axis

Tags: modeling, faces

Using blender 2.75

I make the same planes except they are symmetrical on the y axis.
One of the planes bend in the middle horizontally and one vertically. This has happened before and is really bugging me. does anyone know why?

[image: Looking from above.]

[image]

As you can see they should be the same but for some reason they are bent different to accommodate the odd shape.

Comment: Non-planar faces like those in your mesh are generally avoided, precisely for this reason. The way those faces are triangulated will affect their shape, so their shape is really undefined. There is no guarantee they will be triangulated the same way everywhere (e.g. they might appear different in the render). To fix this undefined behavior, you could triangulate them yourself, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21411/599 but this creates topology which may be difficult to work with depending on what you're doing. Ideally you could create topology made entirely of quads, with no tris or ngons.