# Need help with fixing a dragon wing

Tags: modeling

Been looking for an answer for this for a while now, but to no avail. It's a pretty simple fix I imagine.
I'm trying to find a way to make the edges of the wings smoother, but due to the fact both wings contain lots of triangles, it's been almost impossible for me to find a way to make the bottom look less jagged. I know adding more vertices would solve the issue, but loop cuts won't work for this sadly.
[image]

In the below image I thought it was appropriate to point out the wings contain a space in between them (this isn't a double vertex error btw). 
[image]

Comment: read about non-planar geometry here. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21411/1853

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? If you're using 2.77, there's a button called 'Shade Smooth' and 'Smooth', try applying those onto the edges to smooth it out, this helped me whenever I had to smooth out certain spots on my dragon mesh.