# Shadows on my Low poly model after applying normal map

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have been working on a model of a weapon and am currently working on baking my normal maps. however after it is finished and I import it into substance designer for texturing I get this shadow on the model. I have checked that my normals are facing the proper way, checked for any doubles. to no avail

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Images Link: [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2C7L.jpg)

Why is my model doing this, and how can I fix it?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also add an image of your object in wireframe mode? (Or better yet - in shaded editmode)

Comment: I added the wire frame to the album.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18055/strange-lighting-problem-with-normals/18058#18058 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21407/weird-connecting-lines-with-no-edges-vertices/21411#21411

Comment: The issue you have is that you have non-planar faces. Some vertices on your quads are in different planes, creating a deformations that cannot be represented cleanly with the existing topology.

Comment: Im confused as neither link really helped me any. some of the faces that are completely flat are having this issue as well. so im not sure if it's a non-planar issue. Also there arent any ngons in this model either.

Comment: Is there a place were i can easily upload my blender file maybe being able to look at it might help a bit.